# Python logger has no attribute 'info', 'debug'

Tags: python, python-3.8, python-3.9, python-logging

I have a class that I use to have a single logger across my project.

```
import os
from logging import DEBUG, FileHandler, Formatter, Logger, StreamHandler, getLogger
from typing import Set


class SingleLogger:
    __logger: Logger = None  # type: ignore
    __handler: StreamHandler = None  # type: ignore
    __logging_files: Set[str] = set()

    @classmethod
    def __create_and_configure_logger(cls) -> None:
        if cls.__logger is not None:
            return

        logger = getLogger("shared_logger")
        logger.level = DEBUG

        stream_handler = StreamHandler()
        stream_handler.level = DEBUG
        stream_handler.formatter = Formatter(
            "%(asctime)s %(name)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s"
        )
        __handler = stream_handler
        logger.addHandler(__handler)

        cls.__logger = logger

    @classmethod
    def add_filehandler_to_shared_logger(
        cls, file: str = "/tmp/gipcheslogs.txt", for_notebook: bool = False
    ) -> None:
        if file in cls.__logging_files:
            return

        try:
            if not os.path.exists(file):
                with open(file=file, mode="w", encoding="utf-8") as log_file:
                    log_file.write("")
                    log_file.close()
        except IOError:
            return

        cls.__logging_files.add(file)
        file_handler = FileHandler(file)
        file_handler.level = DEBUG
        file_handler.formatter = Formatter(
            "%(asctime)s %(name)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s"
        )

        cls.shared_logger.addHandler(file_handler)

        if for_notebook:
            cls.__logger.removeHandler(cls.__handler)

    @classmethod
    @property
    def shared_logger(cls) -> Logger:
        """
        Returns:
            Logger: the shared singleton logger, and create it if necessary.
        """
        if not cls.__logger:
            cls.__create_and_configure_logger()

        return cls.__logger


SingleLogger.shared_logger.info(msg="Hello")
SingleLogger.shared_logger.debug(msg="Hello")
```

The code above runs with no problems on Python3.9 or above, but when I run the same code on Python3.8 or lower, I immediately get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute 'info'
```

I'm not sure what is the difference between the two version of Python and why that affects the Logger.

Removing the `@property` from the `shared_logger` method and calling it using `SingleLogger.shared_logger().info("Hi")` fixes the issue, but once again, I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're wrapping a property with `@classmethod`. That was functionality added in 3.9... and removed in 3.11, because it turned out to be a bad idea that broke too much stuff.

Since it was added in 3.9, it will of course not work if you run your code on 3.8. Since it was *removed* in 3.11, you should stop using that functionality anyway.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any docs where I can read more about that change?

Comment: @Jacobo: It's in the [`classmethod` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod).